# How to show message after a while in angular

Tags: angularjs

I use from ng-class for div because I want to show message after a while when if is true but delay opacity dose not work . what do yo do ?

this is html

```
<div class="list" ng-show="item.collapsed == true" ng-class="{'panel-details':item.collapsed == true}">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                </div>
```

this is css

```
.list {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in !important;
}
.panel-details {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working [codepen](https://codepen.io/heysulo/pen/rpjQXR)

Comment: tanks sir it was my problem that I use ng-show and ng-class together.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#list').fadeIn(500);
}, 5000);
```

And do not use opacity but rather the display property